# makefile exit with no reason when compile .pc and .c at the same time. very strange

Tags: c, unix, makefile, proc

I am using pro*c in AIX,I want make my `.pc` file compile to a .so libary. And link it. This is my directory:

ls 
    connect.pc func.c get_log.pc main.c makefile sql_err.pc

---

This is my makefile:

```
#Makefile

CC = cc -g -brtl
CFLAGS = -g -c
ESQL = proc
RM = rm -f

MYHOME = /home/xxx    
OBJ = main.o func.o
LIBOBJ = get_log.o connect.o sql_err.o

DBINC = -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/precomp/public
DBLIB = -L$(ORACLE_HOME)/lib -lclntsh

INCLUDE = -I$(MYHOME)/include

.SUFFIXES:  .pc .c .o

.pc.o:
    $(ESQL) include=$(MYHOME)/include iname=$*.pc
    $(CC) -o $*.o $(CFLAGS) $*.c $(INCLUDE) $(DBINC) $(DBLIB)
    $(RM) $*.c
    $(RM) $*.lis

libmydb.so:$(LIBOBJ)
    $(CC) -qmkshrobj -o $@ $(LIBOBJ) $(DBLIB)
    mv $@ $(MYHOME)/lib

query:$(OBJ)
    cc -o $@ $(OBJ) -L$(MYHOME)/lib -lmydb
    mv $@ $(MYHOME)/bin

func.o:func.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< $(INCLUDE)
main.o:main.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< $(INCLUDE)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.lis
```

when I make I get this:

```
.......
cc -g -brtl -o sql_err.o -g -c sql_err.c -I/home/xxx/include -I/oracle/product/10.2.0/precomp/public -L/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib -lclntsh
rm -f sql_err.c
rm -f sql_err.lis
cc -g -brtl -qmkshrobj -o libmydb.so get_log.o connect.o sql_err.o -L/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib -lclntsh
mv libmydb.so /home/xxxlib
```

when it done mv `libmydb.so` ,it exit!!!without wrong message.why?? I also need my `.c` to compile to `.o` and finally to an executable file query link `libmydb.so`.
when I change the squeuce like this put `.c.o` before `.pc.o`:

```
query:$(OBJ)
    cc -o $@ $(OBJ) -L$(MYHOME)/lib -lmydb
    mv $@ $(MYHOME)/bin

func.o:func.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< $(INCLUDE)
main.o:main.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< $(INCLUDE)
.pc.o:
    $(ESQL) include=$(MYHOME)/include iname=$*.pc
    $(CC) -o $*.o $(CFLAGS) $*.c $(INCLUDE) $(DBINC) $(DBLIB)
    $(RM) $*.c
    $(RM) $*.lis

libmydb.so:$(LIBOBJ)
    $(CC) -qmkshrobj -o $@ $(LIBOBJ) $(DBLIB)
    mv $@ $(MYHOME)/lib
```

it give this message,although I have libmydb.so last step:

```
prepaid(wmfe)/home/xxx/src>make
        cc -g -brtl -c -g -c main.c -I/home/xxx/include
        cc -g -brtl -c -g -c func.c -I/home/xxx/include
        cc -o query main.o func.o -L/home/xxx/lib -lmydb
ld: 0706-006 Cannot find or open library file: -l mydb
        ld:open(): A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 255.


Stop.
```

I can't handle this ,very strange,Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `make` will make the first rule in your makefile, but it must not start with a dot. So the default rule in your makefile is `libmydb.so` and that is being built.

That rule is only dependent on the `LIBOBJ` and `OBJ` is not a dependency so it doesn't care about those. It doesn't exit with no reason, it exits because it has done the job you defined for it. There is no error to report.

If you change the order then the default rule is changed and it tries to compile `query`. This has no dependencies to the library, so it doesn't try to compile that.

If you want to compile everything you should have, for example, a rule `all` that lists the dependencies. In this case probably `libmydb.so` and `query` at least, in correct order. If this is the first rule it will be the default and your compilation will succeed.

Comment: Thank you very much! That seems make sence, I will try it later! Thank you!

Comment: Hi,excuse me,may i ask why the second time link faild,I got the libmydb.so the first time.

Comment: @Hhdzhu I think you might need the `-brtl` to the linking step also, without it the linker might only look for a static library, not a dynamic one. Not an expert in AIX though. Something mentioned in http://fixunix.com/aix/493298-linking-so-aix-4-3-a.html post #4